# i'm trying to make a program with pointers and string, How can i fix it?

Tags: c

I want to recEive into a function a string pointer Maximum of 50 charecters and n (number), reverse it  each letter is replaced by the letter n places after it according to A-B (in a circular form - after Z will come A).

This is what I tried to do and its not working a I planted:

```
#define MAX 50
void decrypt(char* cipher, int n);
int main(void)
{
    int n = 0;
    char cipher[MAX] = { "\0" };
    printf("Enter cipher to decrypt: ");
    fgets(cipher, sizeof(cipher), stdin);
    scanf("Enter decryption key: %d", n);
    decrypt(cipher, n);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void decrypt(char* cipher, int n)
{
    int j = 0;
    int leng = strlen(cipher);
    for (int i = leng - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
            printf("%c", *(cipher + (i + n)));
    }

}
```

From the input `abc` `2` I excpect the output `edc`
and I get `cba`

Comment: Explain what `*(cipher + (i + n))` is supposed to do. It is needlessly complicated and wrong. BTW instead of using the `*(a + b)` notation for dereferencing a pointer with an offset, use `a[b]` which is more readable. With this notation you have `cipher[i + n]`,which should make clear what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of issues with your code. As Jabberwocky pointed out, you should compile with all warning enabled (something like this: `gcc program.c -Wall`)

Here's what you need to do:

- Include `stdio.h` for `stdin`
- Include `string.h` for `strlen`
- `cipher` declared as pointer to an array, which in c is already a pointer
- When using `scanf`, you need to pass in a pointer to `n`
- `strlen` takes a pointer, not pointer pointer
- `scanf` only takes format ("%d" for a number), not like `input` in python
- Your code in `cipher` is a bit messed up.

Here's that all put together:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 50

void decrypt(char* cipher, int n);

int main(void)
{
    int n = 0;
    char cipher[MAX] = { "\0" };
    printf("Enter cipher to decrypt: ");
    fgets(cipher, sizeof(cipher), stdin);
    printf("Enter decryption key: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    decrypt(cipher, n);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void decrypt(char* cipher, int n)
{
    for (int i = strlen(cipher) - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        char c = cipher[i];

        // If c is lowercase and becomes higher than "z", wrap around to "a"
        if (c >= (int)'a' && c <= (int)'z' && c + n > (int)'z') {
            c -= 26;
        }
        // If c is uppercase and higher than "Z", wrap around to "A"
        else if (c >= (int)'A' && c <= (int)'Z' && c + n > (int)'Z') {
            c -= 26;
        }

        c += n;

        printf("%c", c);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is probably still a little issue when it comes to the letter `z`.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Also, we need to handle uppercase and lowercase characters.

Comment: No, not related to lower case and uppercase at all. What happens for an input of `XYZ`, `2`?

Comment: `XYZ` `2` returns `\[Z` and `xyz` `2` yields `|{z`

Comment: I think `XYZ` `2` should return `XAB`. In the question there is _"(in a circular form - after Z will come A)"_

Comment: No, I think it should be `BAZ`, since it's reversed and `X + 2` would be `Z`, `Y` `A` and so on. I'll change the proposed solution, please tell me what you think about it.

Comment: Maybe, the requirement is not very clear.